# I've read how to ask the perfect question, but still my question gets closed?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, closed-questions

A question I asked recently was downvoted and closed. Could you please point out any problems it suffers from?

Here is a link to the question: [How to use header to post row from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318316/how-to-use-header-to-post-row-from-database)

Comment: Have you considered using question marks? It might seem like a small detail, but it will help people parse your question a bit more quickly.

Comment: yeah done but why is that thread banned?

Comment: Hm, actually I meant using question marks in your SO question, not in this one.

Comment: 1. It's not a "thread" 2. It's not "banned"

Comment: Mybe but It still shouldn't be closed just for that? ive even included source code. Its just annoying.

Comment: Well, alex, having to read a question that isn't properly written and formatted is also annoying. And you are the one asking volunteers for free help, using question marks to help those volunteers quickly parse your question isn't too much to ask, is it?

Comment: Sure I would do that. Also If someone asked me a question and I couldnt understand it I would still try to anwser it or tell them where they can change it not just close it for no reason.

Comment: The question wasn't closed for no reason. There was a reason why it was closed.

Comment: Well the reason was not valid in my opinion  So it should stil lbe open if you disagree with me please tell me why.

Comment: Ive provided source code though so it should be Self explanatory .This is like Judging a beauty contest on which model is the most prettiest. Everyone has different opinions and usually the most cynical are the one's who speak the loudest.

Comment: Source code is rarely, if ever, truly self explanatory.

Comment: Being a perl programmer jack you should be able to read and understand it.

Comment: Why should I put forth any effort to understand your question if you won't put in any effort towards making your question clear and concise?

Answer (score 7):

> There is the link whats wrong with it

You posted a wall of code without so much as a clear statement of your question. Indeed, the only question marks in the post are those in the `<?php` tags. It's great to include code with your question, but code that's not directly relevant only hides your question.

As a rule, when you're asking for help, you should endeavor to be as clear as possible about what your question is. Don't make people work to find your question. Using question marks appropriately would help. Starting with a brief introduction to the situation, followed by a clearly stated question, will help a lot.

Note that your question was only closed, not deleted. You're welcome to edit your post and make the actual question more obvious. Include question marks. Put the question in **boldface** if you want. See if you can reduce the code to just that which bears directly on the situation.

Once you've done all that, flag your question and ask a moderator to consider re-opening it.

Comment: ok will do thanks for that.